# How to remove Font fill using Blender API method

Tags: scripting, font

I am new to blender scripting. I am trying to remove the fill from a word.  I have been simply copying the python API generated statements each time I perform a task within Blender.  It works fine until I first try selecting the test (line 13) and nothing happens and then I remove the file interactively, the resulting generated code is found on line 15.  When I try to run the script it fails on line 15, with an error as reported on line 18 and below.  The drop and play approach doesn't always seem to work or am I missing a fundamental procedure in generating the entire code.  Thank you for your help and insight.[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Psyonic!  That has worked.  I need to study the API more!  Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing nothing on line 15, which is why it's saying `'NoneType' object`

You need to tell python what object to change the data of:
`font_obj.data.fill_mode='NONE'`

`font_obj` stores a "link" (for simplicity) to all the accessible "stuff" in the object you have created. To change any of that "stuff" you need to reference the object you want to work with.